# Safari's never-ending loading message when an iframe does not have a src

Tags: jquery, safari, visited

I'm using @rem's [jQuery :visited plugin](http://remysharp.com/2008/02/25/visited-plugin/) to do something with visited links on a page. The plugin works by creating an invisible iframe, injecting the HTML source, and comparing the colour of links to see which have been visited. It works perfectly.

The problem I have is that on Safari, the status bar message always hangs on "Loading (X-1) of X items" - i.e. it thinks there is still some resource still needing to be loaded. I've narrowed it down to this plugin, and the fact that it attaches the IFRAME element to the BODY before the src is set (or injected in this case).

I've tried rearranging the code to set the src before the append happens, but that breaks the plugin's functionality.

Anyone have any ideas how to fix this issue? It's not a major issue as the site still functions perfectly well, but it's an annoying glitch that could be confusing to users.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the src to `about:blank`

Comment: I tried that. So far I've tried:

src = 'about:blank';
src = 'javascript:null';
src = '/blank.html';

Nothing has worked so far. I think that setting the src breaks the injection of markup into the iframe document in the plugin.